# Get number of opened connections on MS Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have created a c# Window Application connecting with MSAccess Database.I need to limit a particular number of users(connections)to access the application at the same time.So I want, the number of active connections on the database.
How can I get the number of active connections in MS Access Database?

Comment: Wrong db for this kind of work

Comment: As I know there is no way to do it with Access. You'll have to do in on application level - for example to create sessions table, create record on app start, remove on app leave, some kind of ping to refresh session state and housekeeping process that would delete sessions left from abnormal application termination